# Opencv Mosaic from video

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching, mosaic

I need to do the same thing of this video https://youtu.be/59RJeLlDAxQ but in Opencv. For now I'm doing this thing http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/ with a little modify in the final image merging, but it doesn't work very well. How can I proceed?

**EDIT**
For testing I'm using the video lab from this page http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~holl/CS290I/Assignments/Assignments-3/Assignment3Mosaicing.html

I ran my code on that video and I obtain this:
[image]

It's not very accurate but its ok.If I let the program run, at a certain point my stitcher produce this:
[image].

For the stitching ROIs instead of the ramsrigoutham.com ones I'm using this:

```
warpPerspective(current_frame, rImg, H, Size(current_frame.cols, current_frame.rows), INTER_NEAREST);


        Mat roi1(final_img, Rect(img_loop.cols, img_loop.rows, vImg[1].cols, vImg[1].rows));
        Mat roi2(final_img, Rect(img_loop.cols, img_loop.rows, rImg.cols, rImg.rows));
        rImg.copyTo(roi2);
        vImg[1].copyTo(roi1);
```

Comment: You should run your algorithm until the last correct frame then debug step by step using imshow and checking yours variables to see where it fail then understand why. I see nothing wrong in your code and I have a very limited window. Tell us if you have something new. Good luck!

Comment: Don't know, check your code. Debugging is 50% of the job.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/high_level.html#stitcher-composepanorama

It's available on 2.4.11 and 3.0.0.

Comment: I tried the built in module but it's very very slow (I need the program to be the most real time possible) and with similar frames gives me error. I have to do a frame by frame stitch because I'm getting frames from a stream and not from a video file!

Comment: What do you mean by "but it doesn't work very well" in your question? In which cases and with what output?

Comment: It works well untill a certain point, then it stitch  very bad. I think it's question of picking the right reference frame or it's qiestion of homography. I'm not at home right now, tomorrow I will edit the post with images if you want!

Comment: Can't you help me? :(

Answer (score 0):

The link you mentioned is access deniedhttp://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~holl/CS290I/Assignments/Assignments-3/Assignment3Mosaicing.html
.

what are '**img_loop**' and '**Vimg**' and '**rimg**' in your code? there is some difference between your code and the code you linked.if it is possible explain a little so I  can work on your problem , cause Im doing the same thing in opencv